# Will if else work after except ValueError python3 (beginner)

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am attempting to exit the below block of code by typing 'exit'. This caused an error due to formatting of the input statement as an integer. I was able to get rid of the error utilizing try and except however I am still unable to get 'exit' to be recognized as an input since all non-integer input results in the else print statement at the bottom of the code block including 'exit'.

Is there a way for variables to be evaluated after except `ValueError`?

```
import sys
import pdb
from random import choice

random1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
random2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

while True:
    print("To exit this game type: 'exit'")
    num1 = choice(random2)
    num2 = choice(random1)

    try:
        answer = int(input("What is {} times {}? :" .format(num1,\
        num2)))

        if answer == num1 * num2:
            print("Correct Choice!")

        else:
            print("WRONG")

    except ValueError:
        if answer == 'exit':
            print("Now exiting the game")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("that answer is not valid try again")
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way I see would be to split up your input line:

```
raw_answer = input("What is {} times {}? :" .format(num1, num2))
try:
    answer = int(raw_answer)
except ValueError:
    if raw_answer == 'exit':
        print("Now exiting the game")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("that answer is not valid try again")
```

This way you keep the original answer to your input, while still using the ValueError to exit your program.

Alternatively, you could check for `raw_answer == 'exit'` first, and use `int()` afterwards...

Comment: This technique was exactly what I was trying to figure out and worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the `ValueError` is thrown calling `int` (the most likely place), then `answer` will not have had a new value assigned to it yet. How could it? It failed trying to convert `"exit"` (or something else) to an `int` before any assignment happened. To fix, you'd want to try something like:

```
# Get the raw string
answer = input("What is {} times {}? :" .format(num1, num2))
# Convert to int; if it fails, the raw string is left in answer
answer = int(answer)
```

That way, the original string is still in `answer` if `int` raises `ValueError`.